# Comments webpart and anonymous access

Tags: web-part, social

I added the "Comments" webpart from the Social web part group to a page on a SharePoint 2010 web site. My site is currently configured with anonymous access so I wanted to confirm if only registered users can see the comments.

Comment: Hi - I have edited your question to improve search and give it some more visibility in the topic list. Can you please confirm if you need the comment web part to be usable by anonymous users?

Comment: yes, the comment web part to be usable by anonymous users